# What's not standard in these descriptors?

Tags: output-script-descriptors, musig

In here, about these (indentation is mine):

```
sh(wsh(multi(2, abcdef01/1'/1'/0/*, 23456789/1'/1'/0/*)))#abcdefgh
sh(wsh(multi(2, abcdef01/1'/1'/1/*, 23456789/1'/1'/1/*)))#ijklmnop
   wsh(multi(2, abcdef01/1'/1'/0/*, 23456789/1'/1'/0/*)) #qrstuvwx
   wsh(multi(2, abcdef01/1'/1'/1/*, 23456789/1'/1'/1/*)) #yz012345
       tr(musig(abcdef01/1'/1'/0/*, 23456789/1'/1'/0/*)) #67890abc
       tr(musig(abcdef01/1'/1'/1/*, 23456789/1'/1'/1/*)) #defghijk
```

WALLET tells:

> Output descriptors are part of a **developing standard** for Recovery that WALLET_PROVIDER intends to support and is helping grow. Since the standard is in a very early stage, **the list above includes some non-standard elements**.
>
> **When descriptors reach a more mature stage, youʼll be able to take your funds from one wallet to another with complete independence**. WALLET_PROVIDER believes this freedom is at the core of Bitcoinʼs promise, and is working towards that goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "musig" descriptor function has not been standardized.

These descriptors also don't seem to contain valid key expressions (which need to be hex pubkeys, hex x-only pubkeys, xpubs, xprvs, or WIF keys, possibly combined with origin information or derivation paths).

Also, descriptors currently don't permit spaces inside.

Comment: I also know a secret passphrase and have a couple very large _public_ strings (printed in the same instructions). Maybe they combine those small strings with the former to create the actual key expressions.

Comment: I suspect these small strings are just key fingerprints, which the application uses to look up in a database for actual keys.